# CodeIgniter model insert extra characters in my query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am executing a query in CodeIgniter model here is my code:

```
if($query = $this->db->select('postID, users.userID, users.userFirstName, users.userLastName, postTitle, postDescription, postHtmlContent, date_format(creationDate, "%d %b, %Y") as creationDate, date_format(updationDate, "%d %b, %Y") as updationDate, cover, postType')->from('posts, users')->where('users.userID = posts.userID and postID = 1 and postStatus = "APPROVED"')->get()){
            return $query->result()[0];
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
```

while executing this query works fine on mysql console but with this active record patten of CodeIgniter some extra characters are introduced in `date_format` section. Here is error shown by CodeIgniter all extra characters are clearly visible in `date_format(creationDate,`"%d`%b,`%Y")`part`.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`posts`, `users`) WHERE `users`.`userID` = posts.userID and postID = 1 and' at line 2

SELECT `postID`, `users`.`userID`, `users`.`userFirstName`, `users`.`userLastName`, `postTitle`, `postDescription`, `postHtmlContent`, date_format(creationDate, `"%d` %b, `%Y")` as creationDate, date_format(updationDate, `"%d` %b, `%Y")` as updationDate, `cover`, `postType` FROM (`posts`, `users`) WHERE `users`.`userID` = posts.userID and postID = 1 and postStatus = "APPROVED"
```

How do I tackle this issue any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `false` as 2nd parameter of select so that codeigniter do not convert the format

```
if($query = $this->db->select('postID, users.userID, users.userFirstName, users.userLastName, postTitle, postDescription, postHtmlContent, date_format(creationDate, "%d %b, %Y") as creationDate, date_format(updationDate, "%d %b, %Y") as updationDate, cover, postType',false)->from('posts, users')->where('users.userID = posts.userID and postID = 1 and postStatus = "APPROVED"')->get()){
        return $query->result()[0];
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
```

[$this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: Thanks i saw it somewhere but didn't find any reference as to why do we add this false.

Answer (score 1):

For removing the backticks, you have to add a second, optional parameter (FALSE) to your select part:

```
$this->db->select("postID, userID, . . .", FALSE);
```